# open files without download them in Firefox

Tags: firefox, download

With latest Firefox versions (98, 99, 100, 101) download mechanism changed radically.

Currently, if I decide to open a file using a system application, Firefox downloads it in the *$DOWNLOAD* folder.
In the past versions, Firefox downloads it (certainly) but in *$TEMP* folder; that's makes it **invisible** to user...

**How can I revert the mechanism back?**

*example: I want to open this **[1]** PDF with my favourite document viewer: Evince; I open the URL and Firefox prompts me a window with available options (see screenshot below)*
[image: FF-download]

*at this point I click **OK** and Evince shows me the PDF. The result is exactly what I want!*
**BUT**
*the abovementioned PDF has been downloaded into my **~/Download** folder, too!*

*and here is the issue: I asked for Firefox to just open (Open with) the file, not download it (Save File).*

*The expected (and previous) behaviour is to download the PDF in a TEMP folder, like /tmp, and open it.*

---

**[1]** https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

Comment: Have you tried selecting what you want along with checking the box for `Do this automatically for files like this from now on.`? It's important to remember that default options and configurations for software are going to change.

Comment: If you change the default download location, will it work for you?

Comment: @NasirRiley it does not change the behaviour

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov changing default location simply "does not work" in that new location... it uses new location as well

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Your files could be downloaded to e.g. `/tmp` by default and you say this does not work. How and why doesn't this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `true` the variable `browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir` (accessed from `about:config`).

Credit is due to an answer provided by a user named xanthonin the discussion forum http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3097140

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences and change the default download location to `/tmp`. **Then** change the option to "Ask where to download each file" (I'm not sure of exact English name of the option, as I'm using a non-English locale, but you will have no problem to find out, as there are only two options in the download section).

Seems a bit counter-intuitive, but will work as needed. Ie. all files that you choose to open in your PDF viewer will be downloaded to `/tmp` and opened from there. When you choose to download the file, Firefox will ask you to select a directory where you want to download it.